# File Writing issue in c

Tags: c, windows

I am writing the log file in my c application, the method for writing the file is

```
fopen_s(&fMainFile, "c:\\LOG\\Filter.txt", "a");
fprintf(fMainFile, "SomeText");
fclose(fMainFile);
```

I open the handle, after writing I closed it, but this writing crash my application after a while, can any one sort out this problem, that how much dangerous to open and close the handle again and again, or proposed any other approach for writhing the file.

Comment: One obvious problem is that you're not doing any error checking - this is mandatory for the call to `fopen_s`, at minimum.

Comment: I have apply Error checking code but its not helpful for me.

Comment: Actually I am writing a lot of data, almost 100 lines in 5 second, its write some data but after some time it crash.

Comment: @Arman: Is it really necessary to open and close the file on every write? Why do you do this in the first place?

Comment: @Greg, If I don't close the handle, how much it dangerous for the memory dangling. Or the approach which I am using is dangerous. Kindly explain me.

Comment: @Arman: I don't see any inherent danger in your approach, but have you tried opening the file once at program start and closing it on exit again? Does this still lead to a crash on write? Please give it a try for debugging purposes.

Comment: Ok I'll try your proposed approach.

Comment: @Arman: Another thing you haven't mentioned so far...is your application multithreaded? Is there any possibility of concurrent accesses to your log file?

Comment: I have multithreads, but only one thread write the log file, but the rate of writing is too much fast, its 100 packets per 5 second and per packet size is 400 byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is fMainFile defined? I suspect that you shoud have:

```
fopen_s(&fMainFile, "c:\\LOG\\Filter.txt", "a");
fprintf(&fMainFile, "SomeText");
fclose(&fMainFile);
```

Pass a reference to the fprintf/fclose functions as you did with fopen_s!

EDIT: this answer is not valid, since fopen_s takes a FILE** parameter as stated below in comments.

**EDIT2:** As i said in comments you should do buffered writing (either with your own buffer or using setvbuf() functions for your file). Also, do not reopen/close the file every time, but leave it open and close it only when you really need to (input is finished). use fflush() to force writing to disk (instead of fclose()).

Comment: FILE *fMainFile; I defined it global.

Comment: It seems like `fopen_s` takes `FILE**` while `fclose` takes `FILE*` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9(VS.80).aspx

Comment: I see, didn't expect that. Discard this answer then, the error must be somewhere else. Maybe if you post more of your code we will be able to find it.

Comment: I have a application which receive data from network and write in the log file. The rate of Data input is almost 100 Packet/5 sec and the size of each packet is maximum 400 bytes.

Comment: Then i would suggest buffering the input and writing in larger chunks, say about 16kB. Also, why do you close the file everytime? Leave it opened and close it when all writing is finished. You can use fflush() to force a write to disk.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely add some error-checking to your code, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9%28VS.80%29.aspx for a specific fopen_s example. Maybe you can get some more information that way. Apart from that, your code snippet looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

You must check the return value of fopen_s and only call fprintf and fclose if it is successful

```
if (fopen_s(&fMainFile, "c:\\LOG\\Filter.txt", "a") == 0)
{
  fprintf(fMainFile, "SomeText");
  fclose(fMainFile);
}
```