# problem in using fprintf_s(getting warnings) in c

Tags: c, struct

I'm new in c.I just want to complete my project.a list of student with struct.and one of the option is save data in a file.
I using visual studio 2022 and BTW I can't use syntaxs like scanf or something like that.I have to use scanf_s and etc
anyway for fprintf_s I don't know how can I use it for my project.I searched in stackoverflow and another sites about it syntax but they were not usefull, but vs gives me a warning. it is:

```
sttp could be '0'
```

the source code is :

```
FILE* sttp;
fopen_s(&sttp, "text.txt", "w");
fprintf_s(sttp, "test");
fclose(sttp);
```

and there are some warnings [the image of error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjKNO.png)

Comment: You need to check whether `fopen_s()` succeeded by checking whether `sttp` is NULL.

Comment: [Here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3100469/3386109) to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to open a file with `fopen_s` function, it may or may *not* succeed, so you must check the return value of that invocation.

If for some reason, the file was not opened, then your file pointer variable, `sttp` will not be initialized, hence the VS IDE is showing you the warning.

Modify your code, like below.

```
FILE* sttp;
if(0 == fopen_s(&sttp, "text.txt", "w") )
{
   fprintf_s(sttp, "test");
   fclose(sttp);
}
```